# React useRef changes didn't cause the component rerender which depends on ref.current

Tags: reactjs

The intention of this Upsell component is to render something in certain area (portal). So it will accept a DOM element, and `createPortal` on that. The problem is the widgetDom is always null and cause the createPortal didn't get chance to render.

In consumer I use `useRef` and pass the `widgetRef.current` to the Upsell component. I am expecting when the `widgetRef` attached the real element, `widgetRef.current` changes will cause the Upsell component rerender, but it is not happening.

Can you have a look the following code or the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-pascal-w32fv?file=/src/App.tsx)? Thank you!

```js
const Upsell: React.FC<{ widgetDom: HTMLElement | null }> = ({ widgetDom }) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h1>Order Summary</h1>
      {widgetDom && createPortal(<h2>Order Summary Widget</h2>, widgetDom)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const widgetDom = React.useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box" style={{ width: "60%" }}>
        <div className="box">
          <h1>Ad Selection</h1>
        </div>
        <Upsell widgetDom={widgetDom.current} />
      </div>
      <div className="box" style={{ width: "40%" }}>
        <div id="orderSummaryWidget" ref={widgetDom} className="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Refs by design [don't cause a re-render when they change](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

The easiest fix is to use state instead of a ref:

```
export default function App() {
  const [widgetDom, setWidgetDom] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box" style={{ width: "60%" }}>
        <div className="box">
          <h1>Ad Selection</h1>
        </div>
        <Upsell widgetDom={widgetDom} />
      </div>
      <div className="box" style={{ width: "40%" }}>
        <div id="orderSummaryWidget" ref={setWidgetDom} className="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```